# Error en pruebas 'module is not defined in ES module scope'

Tags: jest, testing

Estoy haciendo testing en una app en react, donde por medio del comando de `yarn test` me pueda ejecutar los archivos `.test` que tengo pero ahora me da un error que dice.

> ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope This file is
> being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension

Y donde tengo el archivo del `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "counter-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

Y en el jest.config.js lo tengo así

```
module.exports = {
    //TODO: jsdom,
    setupFiles:['./jest.setup.js']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude corregir el error que me mostraba.

Tan solo cambie el nombre de un archivo `jest.config.js` a `jest.config.cjs`, de igual manera para para el archivo `babel.config.js` a `babel.config.cjs`